# How to develop a OData query with any-all support for list{String} in kendo Data Source

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, odata, kendo-datasource

I've a class as following:

```
public class Person
{
 public Int32 Id {get;set;}
 public String Name {get;set;}
 public List<String> OtherNames {get;set;}
}
```

How can I create a OData query as following query with kendo data source filters?

```
People?$filter=OtherNames/any(name:name eq 'AAA' or name eq 'BBB');
```

I've tested that odata query on both WebAPI OData & WCF Data Service and is working fine.

Is there any alternative solution for my requirement?

Kendo: 2013.3.1119